# I need to be able to make a video player that detects n number of video files in a folder and play it one after another in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to be able to make a video player that detects n number of video files in a folder and play it one after another in kivy. I am very new in this so pardon my ignorance. thanks a advance

Comment: You haven't really asked a question.  You should post your code, explaining what is or isn't working, and someone will help you

Comment: yes I get it .. this is my first question :).. next time I will make sure of that .

Comment: @ShaahkarSiddiquee you can _edit_ your question, that's what he meant. :P